# Jquery event.preventDefault() messing with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, plugins, responsive-design

I'm trying to develop a responsive website template, and I want the menu to slide out.  I'm using jQuery to write a plugin for it, and it was working great until I stumbled upon a problem.

I call `event.preventdefault()` on the `touchstart` event. This is so the menu I'm trying to slide out will also work flawlessly on android phones.

I wanted to add another alternative than sliding the menu back so I added a button.  I did this using jQuery's `.click` function. But it doesn't seem to be working, and it seems to be affected by `event.preventdefault()`.  Is there a neat way to come around this problem?

Comment: Please, post you code using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Did you use preventDefault() or preventdefault() ? It should be the first one - JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: *What* isn't working?  The button?  The `.click` event?  What's happening?  Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including event within the click invoking anonymous function?

```
$(element).click(function(event){
   event.preventdefault();
});
```

If this is not the solution could you please provide use with a little code, which we then can check.

Comment: It's NOT the solution for sure, because javascript is case sensitive.